# rosbridge and web server over the internet

Tags: ros, rosbridge, rosbridge-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have rosbridge server running on a robot and a linux web server running on another network.
My question is: what is the right way to connect the rosbridge node with the web server?
I was thinking about ssh tunneling. Is this the right way?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229482/rosbridge-and-web-server-over-the-internet/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Clients such as a web browser will talk directly to rosbridge using something like roslibjs. The web server is only responsible for severing the client the webpage, it does not need to talk directly to rosbridge, only the client browser will. Therefore, the IP and port 9090 of the rosbridge server on the robot must be available to the client.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2016-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2016-03-21**:
Thanks for clarification. I have to solve the visibility issue, from the client to the rosbridge server.